# AJAX post in PHP returns html comment; renders json return useless

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an index.html page that makes an AJAX request to a PHP page; the expected return is JSON. The code seems to work well. However for some random reason, my PHP file sometimes returns `<!-- end of php tag-->` before the json text.

The return that breaks the program looks like this:

`<!-- end of php tag-->{"success":true,"message":"Informacion registrada. Porfavor verifica su telefono."}`

That html comment breaks the whole thing. The index.html file can't process the file correctly when that comment is returned. I have no idea why that comment gets returned or where it comes from. Its not in any of my code... and when I troubleshoot it, it seems to go away. But then I submit different values and it comes back... Very weird behavior..

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you searched all of your files for this text, including all templates, and all related libraries that you are using? This text does not come out of nowhere, it must be your code.

Comment: Haha... I don't know if to be mad or happy that that worked... Thanks a ton. (I had done a search before but it was only in my subdirectory, and not the whole directory... some library I used ended with that) -- Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect you have something like this somewhere:

```
<?php

    stuff
?>
<!-- end of php tag -->
```

Everything outside of the `<?php` and `?>` tags will get output to the browser.

Find it and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself... Seems strange that html comments would break the JSON response, but it does.

I had to move a bunch of my html comments just 2 lines down to be within the php tags  to fix the problem.